# Finding Old computers using Powershell, then sending via email

Tags: powershell-4.0

I'm new to Powershell and I'm trying to send the output via email. If I run the script in Powershell, it gives me the correct output, but the email only gives me the SearchBase OUs.

```
# The 60 is the number of days from today since the last logon
$xDays = (Get-Date).AddDays(-20)

# List of SearchBase locations
$OUs = @('OU1','OU2','OU3','OU4')

$OUs | ForEach-Object {Get-ADComputer -Property Name,CanonicalName,OperatingSystem,LastLogonDate -Filter {LastLogonDate -le $xDays -and Name -NotLike '*-vm'} -SearchBase $_ } | Fl Name,OperatingSystem,CanonicalName,lastLogonDate | Out-String

$From = "x@y.com"
$Rcpnt = "y@y.com"
$SMTP = "smtp.y.com"
$SUBJECT = "Old Computers Report from $env:ComputerName.$env:USERDNSDOMAIN - $((Get-Date).ToShortDateString())"
$Mail_Body = $OUs | Out-String
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your are exporting $OUs variable as body.
First you need to store your computers in a variable , try this

```
# The 60 is the number of days from today since the last logon
$xDays = (Get-Date).AddDays(-20)

# List of SearchBase locations
$OUs = @('OU1','OU2','OU3','OU4')

$OUs | ForEach-Object {$computers = Get-ADComputer -Property Name,CanonicalName,OperatingSystem,LastLogonDate -Filter {LastLogonDate -le $xDays -and Name -NotLike '*-vm'} -SearchBase $_ } | Fl Name,OperatingSystem,CanonicalName,lastLogonDate | Out-String

$From = "x@y.com"
$Rcpnt = "y@y.com"
$SMTP = "smtp.y.com"
$SUBJECT = "Old Computers Report from $env:ComputerName.$env:USERDNSDOMAIN - $((Get-Date).ToShortDateString())"
$Mail_Body = $computers | Out-String
```